# From String textBox to hex 0x byte[] c#

Tags: c#, hex, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you convert Byte Array to Hexadecimal String, and vice versa, in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa-in-c)

I have a textbox that gets in input the string "AA 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99 AA BB CC DD EE FF", i split it to have the String[], but now i have to get a byte[] like this:

```
byte[] b6 = new byte[20] {0xAA,0x11,0x22,0x33,0x44,0x55,0x66,0x77,0x88 ,0x99 ,0xAA ,0xBB,0xCC ,0xDD ,0xEE,0xFF};
```

can someone suggest me how to do it. I tried to use `Convert.ToByte` but I get the error of impossible to convert `String` to `byte.` And i don't have to convert the values in hex, only to add the `0x` in front of each byte and add to the byte array.

Comment: it's not a duplicate because i tried to apply the things said in that post but i didn't get what i need. If I upply the 16 parse or Hex parse i get other values, not the format 0x but array byte with values like "170,17,..." so it convert the 0x11 in 17 decimal but i want to get 0x11.

Comment: @user1788654, see my answer, I explained how to display bytes as you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string input = "AA 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99 AA BB CC DD EE FF";
byte[] bytes = input.Split().Select(s => Convert.ToByte(s, 16)).ToArray();
```

Comment: I tried this solution, but i don't get what i want, i get a byte array with values like "170,17,..." so it convert 11 to 17. But i want to get 0x11. I know that 11 is 17 in decimal but i need the hex format to get in input to a reader.

Comment: I need to get in input: "AA 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99 AA BB CC DD EE FF" and in output byte array with the same values, only with the "0x" in fronto of each bit.

Comment: @user1788654, 0x11 is the same as 17... they're just different representation of the same value (hexadecimal and decimal). It doesn't make sense to say that you want it as 0x11; this is just a notation used in code, at runtime the value isn't represented as either 0x11 or 17, but in binary (00010111). What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i have an array byte: byte[] b6 = new byte[23] {0x02,0x01,0x12,0x77,0x04,0xAA,0x11,0x22,0x33,0x44,0x55,0x66,0x77,0x88 ,0x99 ,0xAA ,0xBB,0xCC ,0xDD ,0xEE,0xFF,0xCA,0x03}.  The bytes of this array will be put in input to a serialport connection, and it's the command that this serial port register for the activity: write. So i need this 0x.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
int.Parse(hexValue, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

for every splitted element of the string and add it to a List.

```
List<Byte> bytes = new List<Byte>();
foreach (var splittedValue in hexString.Split(' ')) {
    bytes.Add(int.Parse(splittedValue, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));
} 
return bytes.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `byte.Parse`:

```
byte[] bytes = str.Split().Select(s => byte.Parse(s, NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToArray();
```

To display bytes in hexadecimal representation use ToString override:

```
foreach (var b in bytes)
{
    Console.WriteLine("0x{0:X}", b);
    //or Console.WriteLine("0x" + b.ToString("X"));
}
```

You also can use "X" format and its modifications in `string.Format`.

Comment: `byte.Parse` parses the string as decimal by default, not hexadecimal, so this won't work

Comment: @2kay thank you for the representation, but i don't get the 0xAA, but only AA. I was trying to ask you how to get the 0xAA format. So i print 0xAA not only AA, because after i have to get this value in input to another procedure.

Comment: @user1788654, edited. Seems like you can get leading "0x" only by concatenating "0x" and hex representation of byte :(

Answer (score -3):

you could use [tostring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) function

Comment: This won't work at all.